# How to get the beautifulsoup faster getting all elements in scraping a web page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request, lxml

How get the  beautifulsoup scraper faster?
This code looks slow, any way to do it faster?

```
def getNews():
        tic=time.perf_counter()
        requests_session = requests.Session()
        scrapy = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/markets?mod=top_nav ').content
        product = SoupStrainer('div', {'id': 'collection__elements j-scrollElement'})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(scrapy, 'lxml')
        for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'collection__elements j-scrollElement'}):
            for div in div.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'article__content'}):
                for div2 in div.find_all('h3', attrs={'class':'article__headline'}):
                     for a in div2.find_all('a', href=True):
                         if a.text:
                            print(a.text)
                            print(a['href'])
        toc=time.perf_counter()
        print(toc-tic)
```

Comment: "This code looks slow". But is it? Please define "slow".

Comment: takes too long to be executed

Comment: Define "too long"

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's more to the story, your code is just as fast as the option below, but mine finds more articles, stories. Which may or may not matter to you. I'm on a home internet with a modern Windows laptop

What times are you seeing that makes you think this isn't fast? Or what do you think it should be? It's running at 1/3 of 1 second.

```
    %%timeit
    requests_session = requests.Session()
    scrapy = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/markets?mod=top_nav ').content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(scrapy, 'lxml')
    for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'collection__elements j-scrollElement'}):
        for div in div.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'article__content'}):
            for div2 in div.find_all('h3', attrs={'class':'article__headline'}):
                 for a in div2.find_all('a', href=True):
                     if a.text:
                        # print(a.text)
                        print(a['href'])

# 318 ms ± 55.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
requests_session = requests.Session()
scrapy = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/markets?mod=top_nav ').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(scrapy, 'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='link', href=re.compile('articles|story')):
    print(link.get('href'))

# 317 ms ± 58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: ok thanks, me was necessary 1.6 sec. Anyway, do you know how to insert all the results in an Html.table in Dash? iterating the results?

Comment: Your welcome. Please form a new question and someone with that experience can answer it. Give it a shot though and paste your code attempt.